# Why is the entirety of this first array being added onto the second, on top of the two values (from the first) that I assign it?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to assign the first two values from the hash array to the salt array.

```
char hash[] = {"HAodcdZseTJTc"};   
char salt[] = {hash[0], hash[1]};

printf("%s", salt);
```

However, when I attempt this, the first two values are assigned and then all thirteen values are also assigned to the salt array. So my output here is not:

```
HA
```

but instead:

```
HAHAodcdZseTJTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding just two characters to the `salt` array and you are not adding the `'\0'` terminator.

Passing a non `nul` terminated array as a parameter to `printf()` with a `"%s"` specifier, causes undefined behavior, in your case it prints `hash` in my case

```
HA@
```

was printed.

Strings in c use a special convetion to know where they end, a non printable special character `'\0'` is appended at the end of a sequence of non-`'\0'` bytes, and that's how a c string is built.

For example, if you were to compute the length of a string you would do something like

```
size_t stringlength(const char *string)
{
    size_t length;
    for (length = 0 ; string[length] != '\0' ; ++length);
    return length;
}
```

there are of course better ways of doing it, but I just want to illustrate what the significance of the terminating `'\0'` is.

Now that you know this, you should notice that

```
char string[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
```

is an array of `char` but it's **not a string**, for it to be a string, it needs a terminating `'\0'`, so

```
char string[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', '\0'};
```

would actually be a string.

Notice that then, when you allocate space to store `n` characters, you need to allocate `n + 1` bytes, to make room for the `'\0'`.

In the case of `printf()` it will try to consume all the bytes that the passed pointer points at, until one of them is `'\0'`, there it would stop iterating through the bytes.

That also explains the **Undefined Behavior** thing, because clearly `printf()` would be reading out of bounds, and anything could happen, it depends on what is actually there at the memory address that does not belong the the passed data but is off bounds.

There are many functions in the standard library that expect strings, i.e. _sequences of non `nul` bytes, followed by a `nul` byte.

Comment: Would you be willing to explain why that is? I just started coding and this is the first I've hear of this

Answer (score 3):

`salt` is not null-terminated. Try:

```
char salt[] = {hash[0], hash[1], '\0'};
```

Comment: Would you be willing to explain why that is? I just started coding and this is the first I've heard of this. Regardless, I appreciate the response.

Comment: @Jord [Null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)